# how to store data in Cosmo Database (not in plain text)?

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-cosmosdb

I want to store data in Azure Cosmos Database. But it should not be in plain text. And I don't want to use the Client-Side Encryption mechanism provide by azure because it is accessible by teams who have access to the Database. How to do that. If possible then how to query the data on that.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you want to do that, but Azure Cosmos DB uses AES-256 encryption on all regions where the account is running.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/database-encryption-at-rest),

> Data stored in your Azure Cosmos account is automatically and
> seamlessly encrypted with keys managed by Microsoft (service-managed
> keys)

Here the service's encryption-at-rest is not accessible from your application, which means it's done transparently to the end user. Which also means that you will never see the encrypted data as the Cosmos DB handles the encryption/decryption.

If you still need to encrypt with your own logic you can use the [Customer Managed Key option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-cmk).